# replacement for getElementsByClassName for IE 8 and below

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I am having some html which looks like this
I need the innerHTML contents for address1 range, city range and state range classes respecively for different std-address classes.

```
<div id="result-list">
            <div class="data">
                    <p class="std-address">
                        <span class="address1 range">some html content</span>
                        <span class="city range">some html content</span>
                        <span class="state range">some html content</span>

                    </p>
                    <p class="std-address">
                        <span class="address1 range">some html content</span>
                        <span class="city range">some html content</span>
                        <span class="state range">some html content</span>

                    </p>
                    <p class="std-address">
                        <span class="address1 range">some html content</span>
                        <span class="city range">some html content</span>
                        <span class="state range">some html content</span>

                    </p>
            </div>
</div>
```

I wrote the below mentioned code which was working properly untill i tested that on IE 8 and below

```
var addArrayX = document.getElementById("result-list").getElementsByClassName("std-address");


            for (i=0;i<addArrayX.length;i++){
                var address = addArrayX[i];
                stLine1 = trim(((address.getElementsByClassName("address1 range"))[0]).innerHTML);
                city = trim(((address.getElementsByClassName("city range"))[0]).innerHTML);
                state =  trim(((address.getElementsByClassName("state range"))[0]).innerHTML);
            }
```

Kindly help me in making this code IE compatible(using js prefererably or by jQuery)

here is the link for html
http://jsfiddle.net/H3HRN/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use jquery then try this:

```
     $("[id*='result-list']").find("p[class*='std-address']").each(function () {
        var address = $(this).children("span[class*=address1]").html();
        var city = $(this).children("span[class*=city]").html();
        var state = $(this).children("span[class*=state]").html();

    });
```

see here : http://jsfiddle.net/H3HRN/20/

Comment: hi Jigs... I am new to jquery..when i used this in my code..it gave me this error... object is undefined
 
// args is for internal usage only
each: function( object, callback, args ) {
var name, i = 0, length = object.length;

Comment: hello Jigs.. I guess I am facing problems because of the classes in the real document.. I have edited the class name in the problem.. its result-list, std-address, address1 range... can u suggest any solution now....

Comment: hey.. what ever your html render plz render in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). so any one understand and easily to solve your problem

Comment: i have updated my answer.and also be tested that this code should be worked on `jquery 1.2.6`. here is jquery fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/H3HRN/20/

Comment: hi Jigs your solution works perfecly fine but only if I consider the html link I sent you.. I have a structure like <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head></head>
 <body onclick="javascript:stickyhide();"></body>
 <div id="temporaryInspDIVElement" style="display: none;">html i sent you</div>
</html> and this 'html i sent you'is the one I sent you' when i run your query it alerts me saying undefined.... kindly have a look on http://jsfiddle.net/BCZnn/1/

Answer (score 1):

In general, if there's a single DOM function unavailable use a polyfill to implement similar functionality in unsupported browsers. For many features googling for `[name of method] + polyfill` will find you a snippet of js code you can include in the page to make your js work across browsers. [Here's one for getElementsByClassName](https://gist.github.com/2299607).

However, if you find yourself having to polyfill a lot of DOM methods it may just be best to include a library like jQuery/Sizzle.

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery way:**

```
var innerHTML = $('.className').html();
```

If you want the child of `resultList` id:

```
var innerHTML = $('#resultList .className').html();
```

Comment: I think you may need to say, that this solution will require jjQuery.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach. Isn't it obvious it's jQuery?

Comment: Not for you or me, but the question was completly without any javascript library, so I doubt the Person, who asked the question knows about jquery.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach. Read the last line in the question: _"using js prefererably or by jQuery"_

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$('#resultList .stdAddress')
```

IMHO, if you need to do a lot of DOM selection, just go ahead and use jQuery all the way

Comment: If it's just DOM selection and the OP is not using jquery's other features then just including sizzle, jQUery's selection engine, is lighter-weight - http://sizzlejs.com/, then you just use `Sizzle('#resultList .stdAddress')`

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery your code will look like this:

```
$("#resultList .stdAddress").each(function() {
    var stLine1 = $.trim($(this).children(".address1").text());
    var city = $.trim($(this).children(".city").text());
    var state = $.trim($(this).children(".state").text());
});
```